# PrimeNg Accordion : Not collapsing if contains dynamic data

Tags: angular, primeng, accordion

**Issue**: Accordion is not collapsing if we are populating tabs and it's content dynamically.

**Angular Code**:

```
<p-accordion [multiple]="true">
<div class="gap" *ngFor="let map of docMap | keyvalue">
    <p-accordionTab>
        <ng-template pTemplate="header"> {{ map.key
      }}<a style="
          padding-left: 10px;
          font-size: 12px;
          margin: -5px 0px -10px 0px;
        " class="info-link" (click)="$event.stopPropagation()" href="" target="_blank">
                <mat-icon class="info-icon">info</mat-icon>
            </a> </ng-template>
        <div class="p-grid p-fluid p-formgrid">
            <div class="p-field p-col-12">
                <div class="p-grid" *ngFor="let doc of map.value">
                    <div class="p-field p-col-10"> <label [for]="'title' + doc.id">{{ doc.title }} *</label> <input [id]="'title' + doc.id" type="text" pInputText [(ngModel)]="doc.link" maxlength="200" /> </div>
                    <div class="p-field p-col-2" style="margin-top: 42px">
                        <p-checkbox [id]="'is-reviewed' + doc.id" name="group1" binary="true" [(ngModel)]="doc.isReviewed" (onChange)="updateReviewer(map.key, doc)" [disabled]="!doc.link"></p-checkbox> <span class="default-text" style="margin-left: 10px">Is Reviewed?</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="p-field p-col-11"></div>
            <div class="p-field p-col-1">
                <p-button id="save-lc" label="Save" (onClick)="saveDocuments()"></p-button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </p-accordionTab>
</div>
```

**Output when collapsing the accordion**:

[image: Issue_Accordion_Not_Collapsing]

**Note**:

- CSS is not override
- Just populating accordion content dynamically which is the list of documents